# java.lang.NullPointerException connecting to Cloud SQL

Tags: java, jdbc, google-cloud-sql

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.*;

public class ConnectionManager {
    private static String URL  = "jdbc:google:mysql://your-project-id:your-instance-name/database";
    private static String DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver";
    private static String USERNAME = "root";
    private static String PASSWORD = "test";
    private static Connection CON = null;

    public static Connection getConnection() {
        try {
            Class.forName(DRIVER);
            try {
                CON = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
            } catch (SQLException se) {
                //Handle errors for JDBC
                se.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            //Handle errors for Class.forName
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        //return a connection object
        return CON;
    }

}
```

I created the above class to connect to my Cloud SQL instance in Android Studio but the above class is returning a NULL which in turn hurts the rest of my code:

```
conn = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
stmt = conn.createStatement();
String sql;
sql = "INSERT into messages (message) VALUES('Hello World')";
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
```

I'm not sure though why I cam getting this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.sql.Statement java.sql.Connection.createStatement()' on a null object reference
```

Am I missing some imports or something?

Comment: What are you doing here? `Class.forName(DRIVER);` You don't use the return value of that method call... Are you getting any `SQLException`s or anything else during that method call?

Comment: Have you added the dependent libraries(jar) for that [Refer](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/)

Comment: @refer Not sure how to do that...

Comment: Have a look here, this solves your problem: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/#enable_connector_j

Comment: @NwDx I am very aware of that link but it didn't solve the problem. You can only connect to Cloud SQL if it is running in AppEngine apparently...

Comment: At a minimum, add a null check in your `getConnection()` class, so that you get an error when you try to open the connection, not when you try to use it.

Comment: @RyanJ I don't understand your question. No, I am not getting any SQLException...

Comment: @dimo414 if I add a null check, what should my ConnectionManager class I return if it evaluates to null?

Comment: @MicroR you raise an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver
```

Only works if your app is running in AppEngine,and remember to enable the connector in appengine.
 If not just use     com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.

The guide is very simple: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/#enable_connector_j

Comment: I see. I thought you could just access Cloud SQL like any other MySQL database out there. And 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' will only work on localhost no?

Comment: I think you can use it, i use a local database to develop and don't  mix with production,but  like it says in the guide// Alternatively, connect to a Google Cloud SQL instance using:
        // jdbc:mysql://ip-address-of-google-cloud-sql-instance:3306/guestbook?user=root
, you just can't use the GoogleDriver because you don't have it, but you can have 2 instances 1 for develop 1 for production

Comment: I tried // jdbc:mysql://ip-address-of-google-cloud-sql-instance:3306/guestbook?user=root with com.mysql.jdbc.Driver and it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Found something interesting here: cloud.google.com/sql/docs/external

So you are able to connect with a normal MySQL Connector and without App Engine. You get the jar-file here: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

To solve 1:

> Authorize the IP or range of IPs from which you will be connecting

you need to get your ip. If you on a normal dsl you may get a dynamic ip, so you have to change this often in admin console of Cloud SQL.

Comment: Thanks. What sucks though is I have to whitelist my IP in the admin console though. I wouldn't be able to give the program to someone else without them also having to get their IP whitelisted.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a cause of one of two things:

1) Missing permission. Try to add these in the Manifest,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.access_wifi_state" />
```

2) Add "jtds-1.3.1.jar" file to app/lib forlder